# Why dot in base::split(.$cyl)?

Tags: r, tidyverse

In R for data science [Chapter 21.5.1](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#shortcuts), this syntax is used in base function `split(.$cyl)`.   Why the dot in `.$cyl`.  The package `purrr` has a syntax for a placeholders (`.`  or `.x`) but `purrr` is **not** involved.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% split(f=.$cyl)
```

Comment: The dot refers to the object that is piped in as the first argument with the `%>%` operator, ie, the dataframe `mtcars`.  So it is the same as `split(mtcars, f=mtcars$cyl)`

Comment: @AndrewGustar   Then why does split(.x$cyl) fail?  Or am I confusing this with purrr?

Comment: Because you are not using `%>%`. It's independent of `split`. Try for example `d <- data.frame(x=1:5)` and then `d %>% .$x`

Comment: It might be requiring the `f=` as well, if it is not the default second argument to `split`.  Usually, `.x` and `.y` are used in functions with more than one argument, so using `.x` in place of `.` might not always work (thought often it does).

Comment: By the way, the `.` notation is associated with the `%>%` operator, rather than with `purrr`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar    That's it `.` is placeholder for `%>%`   Thx

Comment: Note that `library(tidyverse)` imports both `dplyr` and `purrr`. As such `purrr` **is** involved. The answer by Prosoitos fully explains the situation.

Answer (score 5):

The placeholder syntax used by purrr is also used by the magrittr pipe (`%>%`). By default, the pipe passes the left-hand side (LHS) as the first argument of the function on the right-hand side (RHS). When this is the case the `.` is not necessary in the RHS expression.

For instance:

```
mtcars %>% str()
```

works fine and is equivalent to:

```
mtcars %>% str(.)
```

The `.` is in this case totally unnecessary because the LHS (`mtcars`) **is** the first argument passed to `str()`.

So this is the same as:

```
str(mtcars)
```

But in any other situation, you need to use `.` to mark where, in the RHS, the LHS should be passed.

Your example is a little complex because the LHS (`mtcars`) is passed twice in the RHS (the function `split()`):

- first, as the first argument (so no `.` needed)
- then, again, as part of the 2nd argument (so you do need a `.` in that case).

```
mtcars %>% split(f = .$cyl)
```

could be written (though that is unnecessary) as:

```
mtcars %>% split(x = ., f = .$cyl)
```

and is thus in fact equivalent to:

```
split(x = mtcars, f = mtcars$cyl)
```

Comment: this is wrong?  dataframe  %>%  split(x=dataframe, f=factor)

Comment: I just edited my answer: I had not realized that `split()` needs 2 arguments and that `mtcars` was **also** passed as its first argument

Comment: So to answer your second question (in the comment): this is not the proper way to use the pipe. The expression without the pipe is: `split(x = dataframe, f = factor)`. And using the pipe: `dataframe %>% split(f = factor)`. You are combining the 2, so you are passing `x` twice.