# Customize DataTable structure to a List

Tags: r, list, split, datatable, transpose

I intend to transpose the datatable `DT_in` so that the columns `indv1, ...` should be the rows and `POS` as the columns. So for each `indv`, there would be a named column from the `POS` rows, which contains the corresponding values (1,2 and 0). I actually could manage this part through `tidyr::pivot` function. The problem is, I need to do the whole job for each group of IDs in column `ID`. So the output will be a list so that for each group of IDs in `ID` as the first element of the list, the transposed table will be a sublist.

```
> DT_in
CHR      POS          ID         indv1  indv2  indv3  
1   31439_T_A   ENSG00000232325     1    1    2
1   31504_G_A   ENSG00000242474     2    1    1
1   34713_A_C   ENSG00000242474     1    0    1
1   34918_C_T   ENSG00000242474     1    0    1
1   35119_G_A   ENSG00000239715     0    0    1
```

what I tried:

```
DT_in %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
  cols = starts_with("indv")
)

View(DT_in)
  CHR POS       ID              name  value
 <dbl> <chr>     <chr>           <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv1     1
 2     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv2     1
 3     1 31439_T_A ENSG00000232325 indv3     2
 4     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv1     2
 5     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv2     1
 6     1 31504_G_A ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
 7     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv1     1
 8     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv2     0
 9     1 34713_A_C ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
10     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv1     1
11     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv2     0
12     1 34918_C_T ENSG00000242474 indv3     1
13     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv1     0
14     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv2     0
15     1 35119_G_A ENSG00000239715 indv3     1

pivot_wider(pivot, names_from = POS, values_from = value)

Error: Internal error in `compact_rep()`: Negative `n` in `compact_rep()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In nrow * ncol : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

The error shown up when I wanted to do the job without building the list and also because the number of rows in the column `POS` are not the same for each IDs in the `ID` column. That's why I believe it should be done as a list.

UPDATE:
Desired output:

```
> DF_OUT1
CHR        ID       name    31439_T_A
 1 ENSG00000232325 indv1     1         
 1 ENSG00000232325 indv2     1 
 1 ENSG00000232325 indv3     2 

> DF_OUT2
CHR        ID       name    31504_G_A     34713_A_C    34918_C_T
 1 ENSG00000242474 indv1     2                 1           1
 1 ENSG00000242474 indv2     1                 0           0
 1 ENSG00000242474 indv3     1                 1           1

> DF_OUT3
CHR        ID       name    35119_G_A
 1 ENSG00000239715 indv1     0         
 1 ENSG00000239715 indv2     0 
 1 ENSG00000239715 indv3     1
```

As it is seen, I need the outputs to be stored for each IDs separetly either through a loop that gives separate dataframes or in a list of elements named by each unique IDs.

Comment: Your data showed is not giving that error.  i.e. `DT_in %>% 
    pivot_longer(
  cols = starts_with("indv")
) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = POS, values_from = value) %>% nrow#[1] 9` I get 9 rows as output

Comment: Did you try `melt()` function from `data.table`? Is something like this what you are trying to do? `data.table::melt(DT, id.vars = c("POS", "ID"), measure.vars = c("indv1", "indv2", "indv3") )`

Comment: It might help if you show your desired output. Also, try clearing your R environment and running your code again because, like akrun, I don't encounter this error

Comment: @divibisan, I've updated the question providing the desired output!

Comment: I see, so you want 1 data.frame for each gene

Comment: Yes but, since there is a long list of genes, so it would be better to prepare it as list I guess. Otherwise, dealing with those NAs would be a mess! And I need to have the genes id as the name of each elements. So a list that each element contains data of indvs and corresponding variations for each unique gene id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` function spits a data.frame into a list based on a function or variable. We can take your data.frame, pivot it into long form, split it into a list of dataframes based on ID, then pivot each of them wide again using `lapply` to get a list of data.frames:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with('indv')) %>%
    split(.$ID) %>%
    lapply(., function(x) pivot_wider(x, names_from = 'POS'))

$ENSG00000232325
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    CHR ID              name  `31439_T_A`
  <int> <chr>           <chr>       <int>
1     1 ENSG00000232325 indv1           1
2     1 ENSG00000232325 indv2           1
3     1 ENSG00000232325 indv3           2

$ENSG00000239715
# A tibble: 3 × 4
    CHR ID              name  `35119_G_A`
  <int> <chr>           <chr>       <int>
1     1 ENSG00000239715 indv1           0
2     1 ENSG00000239715 indv2           0
3     1 ENSG00000239715 indv3           1

$ENSG00000242474
# A tibble: 3 × 6
    CHR ID              name  `31504_G_A` `34713_A_C` `34918_C_T`
  <int> <chr>           <chr>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1     1 ENSG00000242474 indv1           2           1           1
2     1 ENSG00000242474 indv2           1           0           0
3     1 ENSG00000242474 indv3           1           1           1
```

For a bit of extra context, here's an explanation for why we need to refer to the ID column as `.$ID` in split when using the pipe: [Why dot in base::split(.$cyl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58429203/8366499)

Comment: thanks for the link, I had alreday checked that link before applying the code. Here is another issue related to the output list. I have a DF including a new score for each indv and gene. How add those scores to the element of the list? The dataframe to be added is a matrix where the rows are indvs and columns named by genes. Thank you.

Comment: @Maya_Cent You should make a new question for this with some example data and desired output. My guess is you'll want to do a join your SNP table with the new dataframe before splitting, but that will depend on the desired output

Comment: I actually want to add the gene expression values to the list I made following your suggestion and finally use glmnet package. So the expression matrix contains one value for each indv and gene. I want to add this to the created list.

Comment: As I said, I'd probably `pivot_longer`, `left_join` with your expression matrix (converted to dataframe) on ID and name, then `split` and `pivot_wider`